# Authentication Server (/oauth/token) is not working after migration to latest Spring Boot and Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud

I migrated from

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

To

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

The authentication endpoint (/oauth/token) used to work just fine with old SpringBoot/Cloud, but after the above migration, I can no longer access the /oauth/token endpoint despite valid credentials? 
The response is:

```
{
"error": "unauthorized",
"error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
```

}

Comment: i think it is related to spring-security-oauth components. happened to me too, and i still didnt get the chance to dig in...

Comment: you nay add the error that you hit when you try to get to /oauth/token

Comment: Few days back I migrated Spring-boot from 1.5.3. to 2.0.3 and given endpoint work as expected.  Can you add error stack here?

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: can you share the back end error logs you get.

Comment: For the response I added above, no logs (error, exception) etc are generated in the backend (IDE).

Comment: i think, this required some kind of debugging in code. If possible, can you put code in to public repository, it will help me to debug the issue. Note: As I stated before, spring migration work with me without any issue.

Comment: facing similar issue when migrated 1.5.6 to 2.0.3, did you find any solution or still facing the issue ??